# Is it possible to register against a protocol in Typhoon for use with TyphoonComponentFactory.componentForType in swift

Tags: swift, typhoon

TyphoonComponentFactoryProtocol.componentForType(classOrProtocol: AnyObject!) cannot accept a protocol

As far as I can tell MyProtocol.self returns a Protocol and protocol does not seem to implement the AnyObject protocol (only Any).

Is there a way to use Typhoon for service location based upon a protocol in swift (other than just directly calling the assembly function) or is this just a limitation of swift and typhoon currently?

Comment: Is it an `@objc` protocol you're trying with or a regular Swift protocol?

Comment: @nhgrif custom swift protocol with \@objc (or even inheriting NSObjectProtocol but neither make a difference as soon as you do MyCustomSwiftProtocolType.self to pass as the parameter).  Had assumed 'classOrProtocol' meant I could but could just be the naming from the underlying objective-c implementation of typhoon and it's impossible

Comment: perhaps I'm just trying to fight against what Typhoon is all about coming from a .net world where I register against an interface and inject/service locate based on that interface not based on concrete classes or on knowing which name/method to call/inject

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it appears that this method does not work for Swift, even for `@objc` protocols. It works fine for Objective-C. I've bumped the bug report, to at the very least, report that the method is unavailable in Swift.

While its possible, in Typhoon its generally not necessary to resolve components using the `TyphoonComponentFactory` interface, as they can be resolved from the assembly, example:

```
let assembly = SwiftMiddleAgesAssembly().activate()
let knight = assembly.basicKnight() as! Knight
```

And if you wish you can to proceed from one Typhoon built object to another, [the assembly can be injected](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/What%20can%20be%20Injected#injecting-the-assembly-itself).

Comment: Indeed, as I said above I think it's a hangover from my .net IoC mindset.  Calling the method directly on the assembly means a tight reference to Typhoon (or at least a wrapper interface with explicit properties/methods instead of a single 'resolve') and is effectively, in 'objection' lingo a 'getobject:named:' call always rather than simply a 'getobject:'

To be fair in general I'd do any injection at a single composition root anyway rather than passing containers around but it was interesting to me that you couldn't just resolve by interface.  Thanks!

Comment: You can back your assemblies with a protocol, and inject that (works in either ObjC or Swift). So instead of coupling to Typhoon, you're just injecting a provider.

Comment: This guide applies whether or not you're using 'runtime args': https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon/wiki/backed-by-a-factory-protocol

Comment: If you're using multiple assemblies, then to declare collaborating assembly properties from one assembly to another, remember to declare the property as `TyphoonAssembly<MyProtocol>`, so that Typhoon knows its another assembly. Anywhere else you can use it as `id<MyProtocol>`